# How to resize & move css divisions at same time?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I have a division in which i'll be having dynamic numbers of colorful blocks(that too divisions) at various instances. On clicking the box, i want them to expand & cover whole screen. the problem is, while boxes are expanding, they are expanding at there own position & not shifting in the screen.. 
I used:

```
.elemented1 {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   -webkit-animation: elemen1 0.3s;
   border: 0px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes elemen1 {

   from {
      width: 49.6%;
      height: 39.6%;
   }

   to {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
   }
}
```

This is working fine but i have to put blocks dynamically. I cant write animations for individual blocks as they will be of different sizes.

Comment: Why not use jquery and have it work on non webkit browsers as well?

Comment: Thanx for fast reply... My boss hates jQuery.. so have to do it in css3 only..:(

Comment: Try by using
-webkit-transform: translate(left, top)

Comment: it worked with translate....:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after painful 4 hours i got it.

This is the code for animation:

```
@-webkit-keyframes animateExpansion
{
    from 
    {
    width:49.6%;
    height:49.6%;
    left: attr(left %);
    top: attr(top %);
    -webkit-transform:translate(0%,0%);
    }

    to 
    {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    left: 0%;
    top: 0%;
    -webkit-transform:translate(0%,0%);
    }
}
```

and here goes javascript:

```
function onLayoutClick(){

            var style = window.getComputedStyle(this);
            var this_Top=(style.getPropertyValue('top'));
            var this_Left= (style.getPropertyValue('left'));

            this.setAttribute("style","border:0px;width:100%;height:100%;-webkit-transform:translate(-"+this_Left+",-"+this_Top+");-webkit-animation:animateExpansion 0.5s ease-in-out");
            var layouts = document.getElementsByClassName("layouts");
            for( i = 0 ;i<layouts.length; i++ )
            {
                layouts[i].style.zIndex="-1";
            }

            this.style.zIndex="0";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **css3 framework for css3 animation** as far as your requirement is consent...

May be you should use, [Anima.js](http://lvivski.com/anima/) , it is **css3 + js framework**...

Else you can also try [Move.js](http://visionmedia.github.io/move.js/) and [Animate.css](http://daneden.me/animate/) css3 animation framework...

**Animate.css** is a pure css3 animation framework...

**Note:-** Just before using check the browser compatibility of the css3 animations...

Thanks...